# Import Tensorflow in spyder on mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I followed the instructions on tensorflow.org:

```
./conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
source activate tensorflow
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl --ignore-installed
pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

When I run python in terminal, I can import tensorflow

But when I try to import `tensorflow` in `Spyder`, I got:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

How to get `tensorflow` in `Spyder`?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that if environment is changed at the Launcher from root to tensorflow, I can install a fresh copy of Spyder in that environment.  Once installed, import tensorflow works.